# python eventlet - when to use tpool VS Greenpool

Tags: python, threadpool, eventlet

My understanding is that tpool gives you a pool of native threads while Greenpool offers you pool of green threads(essentially all the green threads are in a single native thread).

- tpool

  ```
  def my_func(start_ident):
      print "start_ident:%s" % start_ident
      print "running in new thread: %s %s" % (start_ident != thread.get_ident(), 
                                          thread.get_ident())

  tpool.execute(my_func, thread.get_ident()
  ```

  results: different native threads

  ```
  start_ident:140735259603328
  running in new thread: True 4616945664
  ```
- Greenpool

  ```
  def worker(line):
      print "worker in thread %s" % thread.get_ident()
      return line

  pool = GreenPool()
  for result in pool.imap(worker, open("test.txt", 'r')):
      print result
  ```

  results: green threads run in the same native thread

  ```
  worker in thread 140735259603328
  worker in thread 140735259603328
  worker in thread 140735259603328
  worker in thread 140735259603328
  .......
  ```

Can someone point me out when to use one pool versus another.

Answer (score 3):

In perfect world [3], you would only require `GreenPool`. But when you call some inevitably blocking code:

- `open` file [1]
- C extension with lots of CPU work like `lxml` or `numpy`
- C extension that uses blocking sockets like `mysqldb`

and the time it blocks for is becoming a concern [2] then you may try tpool to offload those blocking tasks to separate thread. CPython has big costs for that, so it will not always help, again measure [2] everything. E.g. `open('/dev/null', 'rb')` is going to be cheaper in most cases; while `open('/mnt/nfs/file', 'rb')` may take a while to connect remote server.

[1] there are both asynchronous and non-blocking options for dealing with files. Unfortunately, for Linux, I don't know of any solution besides `tpool` like that would really work as a drop-in replacement for `open`.

[2] which you would only know with instrumenting, measuring and watching metrics. There are tons of both awful and great software in that area and you should use at least something to know exact numbers. "It feels slow" is not an information. "Avg. response time dropped by 20% after last release" is much more useful.

[3] examples of perfect world: Erlang, Go, Haskell